# Why R doesn't let me change my working directory?

Tags: r, excel, libreoffice-calc

I'm working on Slackware and I'm trying to change my working directory in order to import a xlsx.

```
setwd("</home/diego/Downloads>")
Error in setwd("</home/diego/Downloads>") : 
cannot change working directory
```

Comment: Just curious. Why did you think that would work with the `<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when directory path is wrong. Two steps may solve this:

- First, check what's your current working directory in **terminal** or use **getwd()** with R
- Second, **setwd("path")** according to your current working directory, for example, **setwd("diego/downloads")**, **setwd("../../abc/def")**, certainly you should drop the `<` and `>`

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `<` and `>` from the directory name.